# Laravel application show blank page without error and log

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-4, die

I updated the project but it turn out showing blank page for all frontend route, I roll back the changes but seems no luck.

The backend works:
http://unionmaterials.com.hk/admin

The frontend, however, every page just return blank page

http://unionmaterials.com.hk

http://unionmaterials.com.hk/page/contact

I have tried log in the controller and

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function contact()
    {
        $this->data['contact'] = Contact::find(1);
        return view('contact')->with($this->data);
    }
}
```

If I change to another view, e.g. `return view('welcome')->with($this->data);`, it works, so I copy the whole content from welcome to contact, but it still return blank page

Anyway to fix the problem ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: *show blank page without error and log* it would be difficult.. where does this `contact` resides in?

Comment: I clear the folder in storage/framework and everything work fine, thanks

Comment: ._. so, i suppose its the `php artisan view:clear` then, because the precompiled page somehow not refreshing..

Comment: Are you using Linux server?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to go to `storage\framework\views` and delete everything from there and the everything worked well.